# Can't figure out how to use dredge with gamm models in R

Tags: r, modeling, model-selection, generalized-additive-model

I'd like to use dredge for variable selection in my models but I can't figure out how to make the code work with a gamm model.

Here is my model:

```
up.5 <- gamm(ln_sorp_P_DM_m ~  s(Clay) + s(Percentile_flow) +
              s(sorp_cap) + s(percentOM) + s(Ammonia) + s(Stream, 
bs="re"), data = Stream_quality.5, method = "ML")
```

Here is the dredge code I used:

```
dredge(up.5, beta=c("none"), evaluate = TRUE, rank = "AICc") 

Error in dredge(up.5) : 
  need a 'global.model' with a call component. Consider using 'uGamm'
```

I don't know how to add the call component that R is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, don't do this. Why should terms be set to exactly equal to zero? Instead bet on sparsely and shrink all the terms in the model.

Instead, use `gam()` (there's nothing in the model that needs `gamm()` as shown) and use `select = TRUE` to turn on extra penalties that can shrink terms out of the model.